# Mark Gmail as read when archiving from notification

Tags: notifications, gmail

The most recent version of the Gmail app as the great feature where
you can choose between archiving or replying to e-mails directly from
the notification.

My problem is that, if you archive it from the notification, it
remains unread (instead of being marked as read). Is there anyway to
get around that?

I'd like for any e-mails that are archived directly from the
notification to be automatically marked as read.

Comment: I don't believe that is currently possible. The only action you can change it to is to delete instead of archive.

Comment: @AlEverett I was hoping there might be way to do it with an alternative app, or at least a google script. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you say Google Script?

[Marking Gmail read with Apps Script](http://mikecr.it/ramblings/marking-gmail-read-with-apps-script)

The idea behind this script is to mark as read any message that is not in the Inbox (i.e., has been archived).

> 1. Head to [script.google.com](http://script.google.com/) to start a script.
> 2. Choose to create a script for Gmail in the little popup.
> 3. Delete all the sample code it gives you.
> 4. Replace it with this (written using [the API reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/)):
>
>    ```
>    function markArchivedAsRead() {
>       var threads = GmailApp.search('label:unread -label:inbox');
>       GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
>     };
>    ```
> 5. Save the project with File > Save.
> 6. Add a new version using File > Manage Versions and enter "initial version" then submit that.
> 7. Do a test run using Run > markArchivedAsRead and be sure and authorize the app when it asks you to.
> 8. Add a new trigger using Resource > Current Project's Triggers and choose to run the above function every minute.
> 9. Save the script again and exit.

I don't know that it's necessary to run it every *minute*, but as long as you run it regularly.

This isn't a direct answer to your issue, and if you have reasons to have unread messages that aren't in your inbox this won't work for you.

Comment: I do have some filters which might directly archive unread e-mails,
and I'd like to keep those unread, but that's a really good start. I
could have a second script that marks with a specific label the unread
threads in my inbox. And then this first script would only
mark-as-read archived messages with this label (instead of all
archived messages).

Comment: This also has a slight bug. If you archive a message and a new message
arrives on the same thread before the script has a chance to run, then
both of them will get marked as read when the script does run. That's
because GmailApp.search returns entire threads, and doesn't care if one of
the messages in the thread was in the inbox.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work with the following *Google Script*.
It's almos the same as @AlEverett's answer, but it never marks as read messages that skipped the inbox entirely (from a filter or something).

Unfortunately, it won't work for you if you tend archive messages very quickly (less then 30 seconds on average).

```
/** Mark as read archived threads which were previously in the inbox (determined by the label "i"). **/
function cleanAndroidArchived(){
  markArchivedAsRead();
  labelInboxAsI();
}

function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:unread label:i -label:inbox');
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel("i");
  label.removeFromThreads(threads);
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
};

function labelInboxAsI() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:unread label:inbox');
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel("i");
  label.addToThreads(threads);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I resolved the issue with @BruceConnor's case, needing to wait for the script to execute before it can work.

1. I created a new filter that looks for anything in the inbox
2. assigns the "i" label (which is created by his version)

Gmail complains that the filter will never match anything, but in this case it does match all incoming messages that stay in the inbox.

The result is that all new incoming messages are automatically "memorized" by this tag, then when you hit archive the script can compare the inbox list with the "i" label and know which ones were just archived, and then mark only those as "read". You don't have to wait to archive, because all messages are assigned into the archive "i" queue.

Bonus: I also set the new "i" label to "Hide in message list" and "Hide in label list", so it never shows up at all. (Click the little arrow next to the new "i" label and choose these options.)

Answer (score 1):

@al-e's answer works, but it does have a little bug mentioned in the comments. I've made a different version of the script that solves this bug and have been successfully using it for a few years. Here's the script that I'm using:

```
function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:unread -label:inbox');
  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    var markUnread = 1;
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      if (messages[j].isInInbox())
        markUnread = 0;
    }
    if (markUnread)
      threads[i].markRead();
  }
};
```